# How to drop columns from a partitioned table in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We can not use `create or replace table` statement for partitioned tables in BigQuery. I can export the table to GCS but BigQuery generates then multiple JSON files that can not be imported into a table in once. Is there a safe way to drop a column from a partitioned table? I use BigQuery's web interface.

Comment: You can just write a view using `except` and `NULL`ing out the value in future partitions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This solution does not seem sustainable long-term. If you want to update your schema multiple times, you'll end up with a root table full of deprecated columns.

Comment: Also, using a view will not delete the underlying data. Maybe there is a reason to delete the actual data (e.g. confidential information).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830133/is-it-possible-to-remove-a-column-from-a-partitioned-table-in-google-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

Renaming a column is not supported by the Cloud Console, the classic BigQuery web UI, the bq command-line tool, or the API. If you attempt to update a table schema using a renamed column, the following error is returned: BigQuery error in update operation: Provided Schema does not match Table project_id:dataset.table.

There are two ways to manually rename a column:

1. Using a SQL query: choose this option if you are more concerned about simplicity and ease of use, and you are less concerned about costs.
2. Recreating the table: choose this option if you are more concerned about costs, and you are less concerned about simplicity and ease of use.

If you want to drop a column you can either:

- Use a SELECT * EXCEPT query that excludes the column (or columns) you want to remove and use the query result to overwrite the table or to create a new destination table
- You can also remove a column by exporting your table data to Cloud Storage, deleting the data corresponding to the column (or columns) you want to remove, and then loading the data into a new table with a schema definition that does not include the removed column(s). You can also use the load job to overwrite the existing table

There is a guide published for [Manually Changing Table Schemas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas).

**edit**

In order to change a Partitioned table to a Non-partitioned table, you can use the Console to query your data and overwrite your current table or copy to a new one. As an example, I have a table in BigQuery partitioned by _PARTITIONTIME. I used the following query to create a non-partitioned table,

```
SELECT *, _PARTITIONTIME as pt FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

With the above code, you will query the data among all table's partitions and create an extra column to show which partition it came from. Then, before executing it, there are two options, save the view in a new non-partitioned table or overwrite the current table:

Creating a new table go to: More(under the query editor) > Query Settings > Check the box "Set a destination table for query results" > Choose your project, dataset and write your new table's name > Under Destination table write preference check Write if empty.

Overwriting the current table: More(under the query editor) > Query Settings > Check the box "Set a destination table for query results" > Choose the same project and dataset for your current table > Write the same table's name as the one you want to overwrite > Under Destination table write preference check Overwrite table.

[credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62320010/10327189)

Comment: I think this solution is not helpful for me, because as described, I have a partionated table.

Comment: What you are looking for is not supported. There is a walkaround, you can create non partitioned table from partitioned one and apply what I described. You'd need to consider if that's feasible for you

Comment: Hmm so you mean, I will create a non-partionated table X then copy all data into X. and create a new partionated table Y. Then copy data from X to Y. That should actually work :)

Comment: well there's no other way so it's not as bad as it sounds :)